# Building Visual Studio solution in Travis

Tags: travis-ci

I'm trying to build a Visual Studio solution on Travis. I had some successful runs but everything stopped working. This minimal `.travis.yml` fails silently

```
language: cpp
os: windows
env:
  - MSBUILD_PATH="/C/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/BuildTools/MSBuild/15.0/Bin"
script:
  - export PATH=$MSBUILD_PATH:$PATH
  - MSBuild.exe -help
```

The jobs ends and fails with [no output](https://travis-ci.org/JanC/XPlaneConnect/builds/534724568#L34)

The similar travis.yml worked quite fine. [See here](https://travis-ci.org/JanC/XPlaneConnect/jobs/534123814) but now any windows command seems to fail silently